# Issue with running postgres commands in local windows machine. Runs successfully in Linux, Mac, but fails in windows

Tags: linux, windows, postgresql

I am setting up postgres in local windows machine and got it installed successfully, but facing issues with importing dump. The command

```
psql -U user db_name < sql_plus_dump.psql
```

is not working.
Its not giving any error, but nothing happens.
Whenever `psql -U` is typed, it asks for login to `-U`, as its not recognizing user. Any thoughts?

Tried reinstalling postgres

```
psql -U user_name db_name < sql_plus_dump.psql
```

Comment: You have to run it in `cmd.exe`.

Comment: I ran it in command prompt, as administrator

Comment: https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/postgresql/import-and-export-a-postgresql-database
This is what I was trying to refer, the statement:
psql -U username dbname < dbexport.pgsql
is not running in windows

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're running psql under git bash or something similar, not under cmd.exe or powershell.

The first solution is to run it under cmd or powershell. This is because psql detects something that bash doesn't provide and thinks it's running headless, thus doesn't print extra stuff out.

What I've done is set up some shell script wrappers that a) create the PGPASSFILE, and b) detects whether the command line is interactive or not (`-f` or `-c` given on the command line).  If it's interactive, uses `start` to start a new window with cmd.exe, otherwise just run it locally with `PGPASSFILE` set. The `PGPASSFILE` allows me to bypass the password query (since it's now auto-read from disk), and then the rest of my sql file gets run fine, though I use `-f` instead of `<`.

It was a bit of a pain to set up, but given my preference for command line over pgadmin, it was worth it to me.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I am running it on command prompt as administrator.

postgres=> psql postgres user_name db_dest < db_source.psql;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "psql"
LINE 1: psql postgres user_name db_dest < db_source.psql;

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I am running it on command prompt as administrator.

postgres=> psql postgres user_name db_dest < db_source.psql;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "psql"
LINE 1: psql postgres user_name db_dest < db_source.psql;

To add on, I've environment variables updated.
I am able to create DATABASE, ALTER ROLE, etc, but facing this error while trying to import a db schema, as this command was originally designed for unix machines but I am running in windows.

Other teammates with mac os are able to execute this in their machines.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who helped to debug this, further research on this proved that the command "psql -U user_name db_name < sql_plus_dump.psql" doesn't work as expected in windows machines and I resolved this issue by using a docker container for running postgres. 
Hope this helps someone who might face this issue in future.